# Magento2 - Add a phtml above footer on category pages

Tags: layout, magento2.2

I want to have a phtml file load only on the category pages . So In a specific category in the design tab I put the below code in the design layout xml textarea.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
<container name="categoryugc" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="ugc">
    <block class="category-ugc" name="bottom.ugc.div" template="category-ugc.phtml"/>
</container>
```

I then created the category-ugc.phtml file in

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Smartwave_Porto/templates/html/
```

I cleared cache and refreshed the page but it still doesnt show the needed phtml page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add your phtml in all category pages.

**Theme :**

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Theme/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
            <container name="categoryugc" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="ugc">
                <block class="Vendor\Name\Block\Block" name="bottom.ugc.div" template="category-ugc.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>        
    </body>
</page>
```

**Module :**

If you have a **module** for that, add it on it instead:

> app/code/Vendor/Name/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
            <container name="categoryugc" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="ugc">
                <block class="Vendor\Name\Block\Block" name="bottom.ugc.div" template="Vendor_Name::category-ugc.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>        
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: You're welcome, good luck !